# Why file /resources/views/errors/404.blade.php is not opened on invalid url?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

Working with laravel 8 app started by other developer, I can not show
file /resources/views/errors/404.blade.php(I have this file) when invalid url like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_admin/platforms/2/editINVALID URL
```

I got empty page with 200 Status Code returned
in routes/web.php I see :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
...

/* ========= For Adminside ========= */
Route::group(array('middleware' => 'auth_admin', 'prefix' => 'app_admin'), function() {
...
```

In file app/Http/Middleware/AuthenticatedAdmin.php I have :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthenticatedAdmin
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {


        $uri = $request->path();
        $bypass_uri = array('/app_admin', 'app_admin/login',
            'app_admin/logout', 'app_admin/forgot_password');

        if (!in_array($uri, $bypass_uri)) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                if (Auth::user()->urole == 1) {
//                    return redirect()->route('dashboard');
                }
                if (Auth::user()->urole == 0) {
                    return redirect()->url('/');
                }
            } else {
                return redirect()->route('login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Also I try add logs into :

```
app/Exceptions/Handler.php :

<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

//use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LogoutResponse;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    public function register()
    {
        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
            \Log::info(  varDump($e, ' -1 app/Exceptions/Handler.php register $e::') );
        });
    }

    public function render($request, Throwable $e)
    {
        $response = parent::render($request, $e);
        \Log::info(  varDump($response->status(), ' -1 app/Exceptions/Handler.php render $response->status()::') );
        if ($response->status() === 419) {
            \Log::info(  ' Expired' );
            auth()->logout();
//            return app(LogoutResponse::class);
        }
        if ($this->isHttpException($e)) {
            if ($e->getStatusCode() == 404) {
                return response()->view('errors' . '404', [], 404);
            }
        }
        return $response;
    }

}
```

I do not see any logs when I enter invalid url like :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_admin/platforms/2/editINVALID URL
```

How can it be fixed?

Thanks!